# How can I output random number of chars from text file?

Tags: powershell, random

I'm trying to have random characters from text file, but something is wrong with my script.

My script:

```
#get the cotent of a file to a variable
$chars = Get-Content -Path C:\temp\UnicodeCharacters.txt

#get 5 random characters
$sample = $chars | Get-Random -Count 5
echo $sample
```

What am I doing wrong?

`

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. In order to get some quality responses I would suggest that you add some more context: What is the result you're expecting? What is happening instead?

Comment: Get-Random command returns a randomly selected 32-bit unsigned integer between 0 (zero) and Int32.MaxValue
If you're trying to read in a text document and randomly select a character from there, then I think it's still possible but not as simple as piping an array of strings directly to Get-Random

Comment: _"I'm trying to have random characters from text file"_ Seems like a possible [X-Y Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).  Why are you trying to do this?  Maybe there is a better way to reach your end goal.

Answer (score 2):

Your variable $chars is not a chararray, it is a normal string.

Try this:

```
$chars = (Get-Content -Path C:\temp\UnicodeCharacters.txt).ToCharArray()
```

Comment: _it is a normal string_, Perhaps. It could be a string array though.

Comment: Much better! The problem now is that I'm getting all the char's in separate lines. How do I make them appear in the same line?   https://ibb.co/sVLRKnQ

Comment: @nEMInTRo to create a normal string again use this code `-join $chars`